# How to prevent unauthorized read/writes for (MongoDB) database?

Tags: database, mongodb, firebase, authentication, authorization

Let's say I have a MongoDB Atlas database connected to my server, and Firebase as authentication. My Firebase server logic can check if user is logged in or not. Good. But how can it check if the request to read or update data from the MongoDB database is authorized?

Let's say someone knows my server location and makes a request to increase the 'score' value of a certain user +1,000 in MongoDB (where it is connected to). The malicious-request-person did this by signing in with Firebase Auth credentials, then using the returned access key + secret (i.e. he passed the Firebase authentication) in combination with the malicious custom code to overwrite the database; there was nothing stopping him from accessing the entire database (i.e. he was fully authorized). How is this prevented in practice?

Perhaps I am missing something here but it appears that tools like Firebase/AWS Amplify Cognito allow you to **authenticate**, but they do not allow you to effectively **authorize** use of non-Firebase/non-Cognito services..? I am trying to see how this works in practice ...

Answer (score 1):

In practice, you'll probably want certain tiers. What you're probably looking for is having an API. The API would use the Firebase authentication, but you would restrict all database transactions to come from an authorized user, which would be the API. From there, you can restrict permissions based on certain users and all that logic would be handled by the API.

The key here is that your user should have restricted permissions and your API should mediate his request. A user should never have direct access to the database, this is highly dangerous for your data, especially if it contains anything remotely sensitive.

Your question is very open ended, so I would highly suggest you read on software architecture principles.

Comment: Hi mustache, if believe Firebase (and AWS Amplify Cognito) allow you to restrict access to their services. But how does it work for MongoDB then, which is an external service? Also, I have added now that I have a server that connects to the MongoDB Atlas cluster, meaning that users do not have direct access to the database

Comment: MongoDB's database can also have restricted access by user, though your user won't be literraly a end user. The user will be the service that is making read and write requests to the database and which to requests will be limited by the end user access level to your application.